# A weak version of planarity

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A planar graph is such that one can draw it on the plane so that edges do not intersect except at vertices. Consider a weaker condition:

- We can draw the graph on a plane so that for every two edges that intersect properly (that is, not at a vertex
  of the graph) there are no edges that intersect properly both these
  edges.

What is known about such graphs?

Edit: What if we strengthen the condition (similar to [outplanarity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OutplanarGraph.html)):

- We can draw the graph on a plane so that all vertices belong to a circle and for every two edges that intersect properly (that is, not at a vertex
  of the graph) there are no edges that intersect properly both these
  edges.

Comment: Robertson-Seymour...?

Comment: Do you have an example of a graph lacking this property?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Complete graph on 100 vertices?

Comment: If I understand correctly and you still demand that no edge passes through a vertex that is not an endpoint of an edge, then these graphs are called quasi-planar graphs. It is known, for instance, that they have a linear number of edges (Agarwal, P.K., Aronov, B., Pach, J. et al. Combinatorica (1997) 17: 1. doi:10.1007/BF01196127)

Edit: It seems they also require that any two edges meet in at most one point.

Comment: I can't edit again, so another comment seems to be necessary:
The mentioned extra condition was removed by Pach, Radoicic and Toth in "Relaxing planarity for topological graphs" (sorry for missing accents), thus proving the linear bound.

Comment: @monkeymaths: Thank you! It is exactly what I needed. If you make it into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graph drawn in the plane (with edges represented by curves that do not pass through vertices except for their endpoints) is called *$k$-quasi-planar* if there are is no set of $k$ pairwise intersecting curves. For $k=3$ they are usually just called *quasi-planar*.

Building on earlier work by Agarwal et al (doi:10.1007/BF01196127), Pach, Radoicic and Toth showed in "Relaxing planarity for topological graphs" that there is a constant $C$ such that every quasi-planar graph on $n$ vertices has at most $Cn$ edges (Theorem 7.1).